# Orthogonal arrays

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

This is from a note I found
[image]
[image]
I don't understand why t cannot equal to 3? If we choose first three columns, each row appears three times, for example, (0,0,0) appears three times in the subarray, which exactly matches the critera which is "any N × t subarray has each t-tuple appearing as a row anequal number of times."?

Comment: But 1 1 1 doesn't appear at all.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your answer. But (1,1,1)  doesn't exist in the original subarray which consisted by first three columns, don't we just need to care existing subarrays which are (0,0,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1) and (1,1,0)?

Comment: That's a matter of how you interpret the sentence, "Any $N\times t$ subarray has each $t$-tuple appearing as a row an equal number of times". If you interpret it as applying only to those $t$-tuples that actually appear in the row, you're right. If you interpret it as applying to every $t$-tuple, whether it appears in the row or not, I'm right.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, I see